# Create column of each cluster

Tags: r

Take a look on the example data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(mpg = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duster 360", 
"Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla", 
"Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", 
"Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", 
"Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", "Volvo 142E"
), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4)), .Names = c("mpg", 
"cyl"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Let's assume that second column is the cluster number. Please remember that in my original data instead of the numbers in second column I have strings. If they are the same that means they belong to the same cluster. I would like to create columns from those clusters and put in every row the `car` which belongs to this cluster. Of course the name of the column should be the same as the cluster name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table`, convert to `data.frame`, loop over the columns and use `ifelse` to replace the 1 value with the corresponding 'mpg' and 0 with NA.

```
 d1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(1:nrow(data),data$cyl))
 d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(x) ifelse(x!=0, as.character(data$mpg), NA))
```

If we are only interested in the 1 elements, instead of a 'data.frame', keep it in a `list` as the lengths will be different.

```
 lapply(d1, function(x) {as.character(data$mpg)[x!=0]})
```

Comment: It works as it supposed to but is it possible to remove those NAs and just put them in line one after each other ? Of course some of the columns will be longer.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Not sure I understand how you wanted the output.   The NA are occupying the rows where that particular cluster is not present.  If you want to remove the NA, keep it in a `list` which can support different lengths. i.e. `lst <- lapply(d1, na.omit)`  But in that case, we need a column to identify the row position.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Or perhaps `lapply(d1, function(x) setNames(na.omit(x), which(!is.na(x))))`

Comment: That's what I would like to have. It is not important for me in which row each car was found. The only important information for me to which column it belongs. Thanks!